# increase linux partion size(file system)

Tags: gparted

i have have a message today that say i need to increase my file system size in ubuntu

```
/dev/sda12       4797600  4233236    297612  94% /
```

[image]

hear is current condition of my ubuntu file system partition. can anyone tell me a how to increase sda12 partition size.

Comment: take a screenshot of gparted partition editor and then upload it to `imgur.com`,after that provide the uploaded link here.

Comment: sorry imgur is not working for me, i upload it in different place.
here is the link,

http://postimg.org/image/3n3uu7s1b/03145f2d/

Comment: from the gparted screenshot,you want how much space and from which partition.

Comment: i want to increase /dev/sda12 , alomost 2g,

Comment: yes, you want 2gb space from which partition?.I will post the answer according to that.

Comment: /dev/sda9 will be a good choice for me, but /dev/sda7 will also work if it do not harm the current os i have installed in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To get 2 GB space from `/dev/sda9` and add it to `/dev/sda12`,follow the below steps,

- You must had to boot from ubuntu live disk.So that all the partitions will be unmounted.And make sure that no one is mounted.
- After opening gparted,Right click on the `/dev/sda9` partition and select Resize/Move option.Resizing it to get 2 GB unallocated space.It was placed just below to the `/dev/sda9` partition.
- You need to move the 2 GB unallocated space just below to the `/dev/sda12` partition,so that it can be combined with your ubuntu `/dev/sda12` partition.
- Right click on the sda9,select Resize/Move and move the dragger to the extreme right,so that the unallocated space will be moved just above to the /dev/sda9 partition.
- Try the above step to move the unallocated space just above to the linux-swap partition(`/dev/sda8`).Now both the unallocated space will be combined into one(2 GB+5 MB)
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda12` partition and select Resize/Move option.Now you can be able to add the unallocated space to the `/dev/sda12` partition.